# What weapons does the Cowboy perk affect?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

The **Cowboy** perk is described as *"You do 25% more damage when using any revolver, lever-action firearm, dynamite, knife, or hatchet, pard'ner."*

I'm curious as to what specific weapons are considered to be Revolvers and Knives for the purposes of this perk. Specifically, do any Energy Weapons qualify? Is the [Shishkebab](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Shishkebab) considered a knife? (link goes to the FO3 version at the moment). Similarly, is [That Gun](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/That_Gun) considered to be a Revolver?

Comment: Going to leave this question open because an exact list would be handy, but I've just gotten confirmation that 'That Gun' does count, but the Shishkebab does not.

Comment: 'That Gun' does not count, it is not listed in the GECK. The Fallout wiki also states that it is not affected by the Cowboy perk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weapons affected by the Cowboy perk are listed in the GECK. Unique versions of the listed weapons are also affected.

- Time Bomb
- BB gun
- Throwing hatchet
- Throwing knife
- Hatchet
- Knife
- Long fuse dynamite
- Dynamite
- Trail carbine
- Brush gun
- Lever action shotgun
- Cowboy repeater
- Hunting revolver
- Ranger sequoia
- .44 revolver
- .357 revolver

Answer (score 4):

I can't (yet) speak to Shishkebab nor That Gun, and in fact this is a speculative answer altogether. However, using [the Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_weapons), my hunch is that the following weapons will qualify:

- .357 magnum revolver

  - Lucky
- .44 magnum revolver

  - Mysterious magnum
- Hunting revolver

  - Ranger Sequoia
- That Gun (confirmed)
- Anti-materiel rifle (Unconfirmed)
- Lever-action shotgun
- Dynamite
- Combat knife

  - Chance's knife
- Hatchet
- Knife
- Switchblade

If I had to guess, I'd think that the Shishkebob would not qualify, as it seems too long-bladed to be a knife. That Gun, on the other hand, I'm up in the air about -- seeing the artwork I could go either way on it.

I will update this answer with The Truth ... Once enough details are known that said Truth can be fully ascertained. :) It may be a few weeks before the Vault is populated well-enough to do so. Among other things, it feels like at least one or two of the rifle types should qualify, but none of the artwork looks lever-action.